# How to get a reference to a JCA connector from a Message-Driven Bean (Eclipse)?

Tags: eclipse, udp, java-ee-6, jca

My goal is to listen on incoming datagram packets, processing them, saving the information in memory and allowing access to it via web. I'm a beginning Java EE developer. I decided to use a servlet (web access), singleton (memory storage) and message-driven bean with resource adapter (to tap into a UDP socket).

I'm trying to execute this example in Eclipse 4.2: http://www.apprigger.com/2011/06/javaee-udp-resource-adapter-example/, but am stuck with the development of the MDB.

So far, I have created a Connector Project, Dynamic Web Project and an EAR project that references them both. I'm trying to run this on GlassFish 3.x.

I'm stuck with creating a MDB inside the Dynamic Web Project. Eclipse asks for a Message listener interface, but I cannot point to the UDPMessageListener (not in classpath), even though the dynamic Web project references the connector project. Do I need to export the connector project classes as a JAR and put it inside WEB-INF/lib folder? But then my EAR would be loading these UDP classes twice - once from the connector project itself, second from inside the jar. I'm really confused how to deploy this properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If still relevant, are you planning on using as embededd rar or external connector ?

Comment: I ended up creating a EAR in Eclipse, which allows me to reference RAR classes in Web project. Once deployed on GlassFish, RAR is part of the EAR. I understand this is an embedded case. How would I do it with an external connector?

Comment: MDB is an EJB, you can't create it in the Web Module you must use an EJB module. Regarding the external connector, you will have to use shared libraries for the Listener interface, if you don't need other to use the resource adapter don't do it.

Comment: Thanks! This makes a lot of sense.